# Fabric.js canvas.toDataURL() sent to PHP by Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a problem here when I need create a image with transparent background. I still don´t know if the problem is with fabricjs or with php. Everything works fine when I sent a image with colored background. The problem occurs when I send a image with transparent background.
The generated image is created with black background.
So, let me explain better:
When the user click in save button, I´m sending the string representation of the canvas to php in the server-side, to be generated the image of the canvas. So I´m using the follow function to sending the string representation of the canvas by Ajax (POST function of jQuery):

```
    function sendStringRepresentation(){
        var strDataURI = canvas.toDataURL();
        strDataURI = strDataURI.substr(22, strDataURI.length);

        $.post("action/createImage.php",
        { 
            str: strDataURI
        },
        function(data){
            if(data == "OK"){
                $("#msg").html("Image created.");
        }
        else{
            $("#msg").html("Image not created.");
            }
        });
    }
```

In PHP file I´m using the follow code to generate the image:

```
    // createImage.php

    $data = base64_decode($_POST["str"]);

    $urlUploadImages = "../uploads/img/";
    $nameImage = "test.png";

    $img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

    if($img) {
        imagepng($img, $urlUploadImages.$nameImage, 0);
        imagedestroy($img);

        // [database code]

        echo "OK";
    }
    else {
        echo 'ERROR';
    }
```

Again, the problem is just with background transparent canvas. With colored background everything works fine.

Answer (score 3):

The last step is quite the opposite:

```
imagecopyresampled( $img, $alpha_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h );
```

And voila! The image is transparent!

Answer (score 2):

Why did you use GD for this? You can use file_put_contents for save png file from your canvas.

// createImage.php

```
$data = base64_decode($_POST["str"]);

$urlUploadImages = "../uploads/img/test.png";
file_put_contents($urlUploadImages, $data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is exactly the problem you're experiencing, but some of the GD library's `imagecreate*` functions create images without the alpha channel.

The workaround I've found is to create an image using `imagecreatetruecolor` and copy your transparent image onto it.

Try a process like this:

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$w = imagesx($img);
$h = imagesy($img);
$alpha_image = imagecreatetruecolor( $w, $h );
imagecopyresampled( $alpha_image, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h );
```

That should ensure that you end up with a "true color" image with the proper alpha channel.

Comment: I try use your solution, but I´m still getting a black background instead a image with tranparent background.
Something that I noticied is that the final image has better look with your solution. Before, with my code, the final image has a uggly white serrated border in a png image and serrated border in texts that I put inside the canvas. Now, using your code sugestion, this uggly serrated border has no more in the final image. That´s good, but I still have the problem with transparent background.
my: [link](http://f.imgtmp.com/puy05.png)
your: [link](http://f.imgtmp.com/EGWel.png)

Comment: Now I resolve it. I´m using new function of GD lib of PHP.
The problem is in PHP not in Fabric.js.
Check this [link](https://gist.github.com/2149853)

Comment: Great, glad you were able to work it out. <strike>What was the function you ended up having to use?</strike> oh, never mind, I just saw your gist. So you had to explicitly fill the true color image with full transparency before copy your source onto it. Huh. wtfphp for real.

Answer (score 0):

JPG toDataURL transforms transparent background to black.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and added this
 
   **imageAlphaBlending($img, true);

   imageSaveAlpha($img, true);**
to rodrigopandini's code and it works perfect now.:)

```
 // createImage.php

$data = base64_decode($_POST["str"]);

$urlUploadImages = "../uploads/img/";
$nameImage = "test.png";

      $img = imagecreatefromstring($data);

      imageAlphaBlending($img, true);
      imageSaveAlpha($img, true);

if($img) {
    imagepng($img, $urlUploadImages.$nameImage, 0);
    imagedestroy($img);

    // [database code]

    echo "OK";
    }
     else {
          echo 'ERROR';
          }
```